# Grepping in R for a particular pattern

Tags: r, regex

I had a question about `grep` function in R.
I have a string like this:

```
"160627_NB551043_0004_AHCJCWBGX"
```

I dont need the whole name. What I need is only `1043`. Its always going to be the last 4 digits in the NB section. Do you know how I can grep that with R

Answer (score 1):

`sub` is more suitable for your case here:

```
sub(".*NB\\d{2}(\\d{4}).*", "\\1", "160627_NB551043_0004_AHCJCWBGX")
# [1] "1043"
```

Or you can use `str_extract` from `stringr` package:

```
str_extract("160627_NB551043_0004_AHCJCWBGX", "(?<=NB\\d{2})\\d{4}")
# [1] "1043"
```

`(?<=NB\\d{2})\\d{4}` finds out the four digits following the pattern `NB\\d{2}`.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Cool I didnt even know about that function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In base R it's very similar to extract - `regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=NB\\d{2})\\d{4}",x,perl=TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to the one given by Psidom, but I'll consider the following **what if**:
*What if after _NB you don't know how many digits are there? What if there are 7 or more digits?*

The approach would be to capture all the digits between `_NB` and `_`:

```
NBdigits = sub(".*_NB(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", "160627_NB551043_0004_AHCJCWBGX")
```

which gives:

```
[1] "551043"
```

and then get the last 4 digits by taking modulus 10000:

```
last4digits = as.numeric(NBdigits)%%10000
```

Result:

```
[1] 1043
```

**Edit: Couple more examples**

What if there are less than 4 digits after NB?

```
as.numeric(sub(".*_NB(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", "160627_NB43_0004_AHCJCWBGX"))%%10000
[1] 43
```

If there are exactly 4?

```
as.numeric(sub(".*_NB(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", "160627_NB9876_0004_AHCJCWBGX"))%%10000
[1] 9876
```

More than 6?

```
as.numeric(sub(".*_NB(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", "160627_NB987654321_0004_AHCJCWBGX"))%%10000
[1] 4321
```

Since you are stating "I have a string like this", I can't assume that there are exactly 6 digits after NB. The only assumption I am making is that there is at least one digit. This solution will work for any number of digits after NB (not 0 though!).

Comment: This works for any number of digits that follow `_NB` and end with `_` (but there must be at least one).

Comment: Or just do `sub(".*NB\\d+(\\d{4}).*", "\\1", "160627_NB000551043_0004_AHCJCWBGX")` and avoid the modulus step

Comment: @thelatemail If you have `"_NB1043_"` your grep will not return 1043. The other will.

Comment: Just make it `sub(".*NB\\d*(\\d{4}).*", "\\1","160627_NB1043_0004_AHCJCWBGX")` then to account for there possibly being no leading values

Comment: @thelatemail, your pattern will not work if there are 3 or less digits.

Comment: Since the original question had only one string example with 6 digits, it is wrong to assume that all the other strings have the same amount. One example does not make a pattern.